# Detect system reboot/shutdown to avoid false positives with monitoring tools

Tags: bash

I have a monitoring tool which checks for a TCP port and then alerts if the port is not listening. I want to make the health check more intelligent so that it does not fire an alert if the system is shutting down / rebooting. I am thinking about doing something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(runlevel)" = "2" ] #I use "=" instead of "-eq" because runlevel might be "s"
then
  #do health check
else
  #skip health check
fi
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you could use a case statement:

```
case $(runlevel) in
2)
    # do health check
    ;;
s)
    # do other things
    ;;
*)
    # skip doing anything
    ;;
esac
```

Also using `[[ ]]` is recommended over `[ ]` in bash since it doesn't split values of variables with IFS and make them subject to pathname expansion.

```
if [[ $(runlevel) == 2 ]]
```

`==` is somehow is also more readable over just a single `=` but be careful with adding glob patterns.

Comment: Regarding `[[` vs `[`, there are probably bigger problems if `runlevel` has a value that makes the distinction meaningful.